# TCP or Telnet server for Ubuntu

Tags: telnet, tcp-ip

I can use telnet to connect to a telnet server simply by typing:
'telnet localhost', whereas localhost can be replaced with any desired IP-Address.

But now I want to do something different and I have this question:
Is there any way to open a telnet server (simply a TCP server) in Ubuntu, which simply shows the connected clients and prints out to console every received bytes as ASCII?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "the collected clients" please?  An example of the output you want, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Are you capable/willing to code? This task is one of the examples explained in the Camel Book, "Programming Perl", published by O'Reilly.